# How to divide a set of overlapping ranges into non-overlapping ranges? but in R

Tags: r, merge, split, dataset, overlap

Let's say we have two datasets:

assays:

```
BHID<-c(127,127,127,127,128)
FROM<-c(950,959,960,961,955)
TO<-c(958,960,961,966,969)
Cu<-c(0.3,0.9,2.5,1.2,0.5)
assays<-data.frame(BHID,FROM,TO,Cu)
```

and litho:

```
BHID<-c(125,127,127,127)
FROM<-c(940,949,960,962)
TO<-c(949,960,961,969)
ROCK<-c(1,1,2,3)
litho<-data.frame(BHID,FROM,TO,ROCK)
```

and I want to join the two sets and the results after running the algorithm would be:

```
BHID  FROM  TO  CU  ROCK
125   940   970  -   1
127   949   950  -   1
127   950   958 0.3  1
127   958   959 -    1
127   959   960 0.9  1
127   960   961 2.5  2
127   961   962 1.2  -
127   962   966 1.2  3
127   966   969 -    3
128   955   962 0.5  -
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the relation between input and output? Right now it is not clear.

Comment: In addition What you have  tried? Can you detail your algorithm at least?

Comment: @zero323 `and I want to join the two sets`

Comment: Can you explain how values in `TO` change? Using `merge(assays, litho, all=T)` will give something similar you showed in your desired output, but `TO` is not what you have.

Comment: @Michele, look at the output data. It is not a simple merge. There are values which are not present in input. Also if I count correctly there is 9 rows in the input data frames and 10 in the output.

Comment: @zero323 I'm sorry it was pretty similar though...:) I saw the three columns in common and the other two, so I got confused...

Comment: @user2844580 the combination `125   940   970` does not exist in your data! It should be `125  940 949` instead

Comment: I have retracted my vote to close. I had not seen the function's title which does help understand the question a lot better. I would only point out that the first row of the expected output might be wrong, as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, the problem is to join the **ASSAYS** and **LITHO** sets. Both share the same column ranges **FROM TO** and these ranges overlap at certain points. How would you divide these ranges to produce a data set of non-overlapping ranges, while retaining information associated with their original range in this case the associated information are the columns **Cu** and **ROCK**

Comment: @Michele, you are right, I made mistake when I was typing. I apologize to everybody

Comment: @user2844580, what you've is ***not non-overlapping***. `949-950` and `950-958` has an overlap of 1 (at 950).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough one but the code seems to work. The idea is to first expand each row into many, each representing a one-increment from `FROM` to `TO`. After merging, identify contiguous rows and un-expand them... Obviously it is not a very efficient approach so it may or may not work if your real data has very large `FROM` and `TO` ranges.

```
library(plyr)
ASSAYS <- adply(assays, 1, with, {
  SEQ <- seq(FROM, TO)
  data.frame(BHID,
             FROM = head(seq(FROM, TO), -1),
             TO   = tail(seq(FROM, TO), -1),
             Cu)
})

LITHO <- adply(litho, 1, with, {
  SEQ <- seq(FROM, TO)
  data.frame(BHID,
             FROM = head(seq(FROM, TO), -1),
             TO   = tail(seq(FROM, TO), -1),
             ROCK)
})

not.as.previous <- function(x) {
  x1 <- head(x, -1)
  x2 <- tail(x, -1)
  c(TRUE, !is.na(x1) & !is.na(x2) & x1 != x2 |
           is.na(x1) & !is.na(x2) |
          !is.na(x1) & is.na(x2))
}

MERGED <- merge(ASSAYS, LITHO, all = TRUE)
MERGED <- transform(MERGED,
  gp.id = cumsum(not.as.previous(BHID) |
                 not.as.previous(Cu)   |
                 not.as.previous(ROCK)))

merged <- ddply(MERGED, "gp.id", function(x) {
  out <- head(x, 1)
  out$TO <- tail(x$TO, 1)
  out
})

merged
#    BHID FROM  TO  Cu ROCK gp.id
# 1   125  940 949  NA    1     1
# 2   127  949 950  NA    1     2
# 3   127  950 958 0.3    1     3
# 4   127  958 959  NA    1     4
# 5   127  959 960 0.9    1     5
# 6   127  960 961 2.5    2     6
# 7   127  961 962 1.2   NA     7
# 8   127  962 966 1.2    3     8
# 9   127  966 969  NA    3     9
# 10  128  955 969 0.5   NA    10
```

Note that the first row is not exactly the same as in your expected output, but I think mine makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use `merge`

```
merge(assays, litho, all=T)
```

In essence, `all=T` is the `SQL` equivalent for `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I haven't specified any columns, because in this case `merge` function will perform the join across the column with same names.